# multiple rewrite for a single url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a multi blog website in which there are multiple domains.
The thing is i need a rewrite rule for the following syntax

```
XXX.domain.com/{any other things} to www.domain.com/domain/XXX/{any other things}
```

Also i had written a set of rules for the below one too

```
^domain/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/cat/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?domain=$1&cat=$2
```

So the things is i need to construct a rule which converts domain to path then again process the other things as follows with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your other rule, you'll need

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteCond $1 !^domain/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain/%1/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+).domain.com/(.*)$ www.domain.com/$1/$2
```

**`([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)`** matches a subdomain.
**`(.*)`** matches everything.

This will rewrite `whatever.domain.com/anything` to `www.domain.com/whatever/anything`.

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: Yes. And changed my answer just a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly, that your redirect example has nothing to do with the requirement:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com/(.*)$  www.domain.com/domain/$1/$2
```

[^.]+ captures the subdomain, the rest is selfevident, I hope.